# ActiveRecord: retrieve mySQL data based on one field in URL

Tags: mysql, ruby, sinatra, sequel

I have a model called "blog", which has several columns, including one called "token".

I want to retrieve a row based on the token that's in a url - for instance, if the user goes to `/blog/post1`, I want to retrieve the row where `token = post1`

In my app setup I'm doing:

```
get '/blog/:id' do
  @postID = params[:id]
  @thePost = Blog.where(token: @postID)
  render 'blog/index'
end
```

When I try to access `<%= @thePost %>` in my .erb file, I get:

`#<Sequel::Mysql2::Dataset:0x007fdec1777318>`

How do I access the actual data from the row here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Blog.where(token: @postID)` returns a list with all matches - even if the list contains only one elemen. OP is using the `Sequel` ORM instead of `ActiveRecord` (Hint is the return type `Sequel::Mysql2::Dataset`), therefore I would suggest to use [`first`](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Model/ClassMethods.html#method-i-first) (or `first!` depending on your usecase) instead of `where`:

```
@thePost = Blog.first(token: @postID)
```

From the docs:

> An alias for calling first on the model's dataset, but with optimized handling of the single argument case.

Comment: I think `take` instead of `first` would be better since AR 4 introduced a forced sorting when using `first`, making `take` slightly more performant.

Comment: @yez: But the OP uses the `Sequel` gem and not `ActiveRecord`. That AR optimization in `first` is not relevant in this context.

Comment: I missed that detail, thanks for pointing it out! I will change my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a relation, what you want to return is an actual record. To do this, use `first` at the end of your `where` call.

```
Blog.where(token: @postID).first
```

Comment: `Sequel::Mysql2::Dataset` tells that the OP is using `Seqel` and not `ActiveRecord`.